# How to secure consumer info without buy an certificate?

Tags: web-application

I need to know how to properly secure my consumers credit card info without buying expensive certificates?  It is possible to use https:// and ssl or tls without an certificate and without scary warnings from browsers ?
If yes what is the safest way ?

Answer (score 5):

> I need to know how to properly secure my consumers **credit card info**
>   without buying **expensive** certificates?

RapidSSL certificates are as cheap as $49/year. Furthermore, properly securing credit card information requires ***a lot*** more than just using TLS and having a CA signed certificate.

If $49/year is a lot of money to you then **I don't think you have the resources to properly store credit card data in a secure and compliant way**. Presumably you are using free or very cheap web hosting which means you probably have a shared hosting environment with limited control over your firewall, logging, and other potentially malicious users on the system.

Having such limited resources does not mean you can't accept credit card payments, just *don't host the checkout or store credit card details* yourself. Check with your bank to see if they have a hosted gateway product, or look at something like [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/checkout) or [PayPal express checkout](https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/express-checkout).

These will allow you to accept credit card payments without needing to use TLS (although I still recommend that you do), because your system will never come in contact with credit card data.

Comment: Seconding the nudge towards third party payment processors like Stripe, PayPal, Amazon Payments, etc. it's going to be much more secure, simple, fast than you learning how to do it yourself since it doesn't sound like you've got a lot of experience in that area.

Comment: Except that on my country almost nobody uses PayPal or Amazon so how i do? Maybe i can never store their data just their harsh ? Yeah have not much experience im that area but i'm with no hurry and i like to learn i did some search on google and saw certificates for like $100.000 so i thought no way i'm paying that much for an certificate but i will check that RapidSSL thanks

Comment: By reading your comments, it seems that you are trying to build everything on your own. Have you talked to your bank? Most have ready-to-use solutions for e-commerce that will ease your work so you will not have to worry about storing CC.

Comment: @Freedom If you can't afford the (significant) costs of a proper secure infrastructure, you should not store or process customer payment card data in any form, including getting the card number to hash it and storing that hash. If you aren't willing or able to deal with the expense of a proper setup, everything payment card-related should be outsourced to a company that is.

Comment: Also, $100.00 is just ~twice what RapidSSL costs. That's still not that much money.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to know how to properly secure my consumers credit card info without buying expensive certificates?

Use a payment provider and don't handle any sensitive information like credit cards by yourself, that is don't even get the information from the user.

Since you are unable to invest even a comparable small amount of money to get a proper certificate you will not be able to invest the much larger amount which is needed to build a infrastructure for securely handling such sensitive data. The certificate used for SSL only cares about transport security from the clients browser up to your server. But in no way it will make you shop protected against attacks like SQL injection or hacking of your server.

If you are still willing to handle credit card data by yourself you should have a look at the PCI requirements for handling credit card information. The costs of the certificate are small compared to the other costs needed to reach PCI compliance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use StartSSL, but those only issues free certificates for a validity period of 1 year, via a automatic verification.

You can also use the new LetsEncrypt service that will be launched Summer 2015.

Comment: 1 year is not time enough any way to increase it?

Comment: @Freedom Why's it not long enough? Literally the only problem caused by a shorter validity period is the (minor) hassle of changing the certificate (if it's paid, there's the additional hassle of buying a renewal, but StartSSL is free).

Comment: So i can renew every year for free? If yes then ok i also hope my service will last longer than 1 year

Comment: yes, you can renew for free. You can even submit the same CSR again, thus you dont have to replace the pub/priv keys, just the certificate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that using a certificate with >1 year expiration, or re-using the same key across multiple years' certificates, would fail the PCI DSS requirements for key management (e.g., 3.6).  Those requirements aren't spelled out, key management is one of those things where DSS references "best practices" like NIST.